# Extend entire stack trace to function levels for debugging and logging purposes - C#,C++ app

Tags: c#, c++, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I want to have an Easter egg to diagnose issues where it failed to make it more convenient to debug.

Like our UI in debugging tools that is intuitive to someone debugging the solution. Need to extend the entire stack trace to function levels (A() called B()-> C()-> (Some 3rd party product).D() caused exception)

Basically I came across SharePoint developer dashboard 2010. It does an output of all .Net methods invoked as well as the service calls along with the Database Queries. We can also output custom messages.

Comment: Bear in mind this is going to have massive performance tolls.

Comment: I know that but I am looking for doing this in pages having forms where I need to generate template data in fields or have user input something. The template data and user input will be validated as per product design and data types. In any case, I need to try this.